# uiautomatorのテストを実行する際にパラメータを受け取りたい

Tags: android, junit, uiautomator

uiautomatorのテストを作成しましたが、コマンドラインより与えるパラメータの受け取り方がわかりません。

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.example.etc -e loop 2 com.example.etc.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

上記は、パラメータ名"loop"、値"2"としてテスト実行しているつもりです。

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class LoopTest {
    private int mLoopCnt;
    @Before
    public void before() {
        mLoopCnt = ???
    }
}
```

このパラメータをテストコード側で受け取るには、どのようなコードを書けばよいでしょうか。

Comment: `-e`オブションで渡したKeyValuePairは、[`InstrumentationTestRunner`を継承したテストクラスの、`onCreate(bundle)`に渡される](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html)らしいのですが、Androidのテスト手法は分断化・陳腐化が激しく、具体的なコードまでは辿り着けず。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたのですが、InstrumentationTestRunnerを継承してOverrideしてもonCreate()呼ばれないですね・・・。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、`AndroidJUnitRunner`継承クラスを作成します。（`InstrumentationTestRunner`継承だとJUnit3になってしまうので）

```
public class MyTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);

        if (arguments != null) {
            String loop = arguments.getString("loop", "1");
            System.setProperty("loop", loop);
        }
    }
}
```

コマンドラインから渡した引数は、`onCreate()`にて、`getString()`で受け取ることができます。

テストランナーからテストクラスに値を引き渡す方法として、ここでは`System.setProperty()`を使っていますが、どのような方法でも構わないです。

`build.gradle`の`defaultConfig`に次の記述を追加します。

```
defaultConfig {
     ...
　　　　testApplicationId "yourpackage.test"
     testInstrumentationRunner "yourpackage.MyTestRunner"
}
```

そして、`Run/Debug Configurations`から、`Android Tests`を追加します。`Specific instrumentation runnner`に自作テストランナーを指定します。

実行すると、`Empty test suite`と言われますが、

```
adb shell pm list instrumentation
```

で確認すると、

```
instrumentation:yourpackage.test/yourpackage.MyTestRunner (target=yourpackage)
```

がインストールされていると思います。あとはコマンドラインからテストを実行します。

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void loopValueCheck() throws Exception {
        int loopValue = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("loop"));
        assertThat(2, is(loopValue));
    }
}
```

`System.getProperty()`で引数の値を受け渡して、テストに利用できます。